# Retaining fragment state along with activity

Tags: android

I have retained the state of an activity while switching between activities by setting intent flag to single top. the activity contains fragment.The activity state gets retained but fragment gets recreated. how to retain the activity state along with the fragment state android by using flags?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `fragment.setRetainInstance(true);` method to tell the fragment it should retain it's state when the activity is recreated:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)